# How can I achieve something similar to this stippled ceiling texture without using image textures?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes, bump

I'm trying to create various ceiling textures at the moment, and this one in particular is giving me some trouble. For reference, a common stippled ceiling should look like this:

[image: Common stippled ceiling]

To try to achieve this, I've been using various noise textures, and the following example is about as close as I've been able to get so far:

[image: Result of node setup included below]

Here is the current node tree for that result:

[image: Node tree corresponding to result image]

Currently, the Voronoi texture has done the best job of getting me a close-to-desirable peak-and-valley effect in conjunction with a ColorRamp and Bump node, and the other textures seem to be possibly refining the effect, but maybe not dramatically enough. Has anyone done something similar to this before, and if so, how might I replicate this effect?

Thanks to the response below, I think that I've been able to achieve something closer to the desired effect:

[image: Side-by-side comparison, plus nodes from the solution with minor edits]

There are a few things that I feel are missing, namely the random tiny bumps, the brush-y, wiped texture (as opposed to the noise texture, which, while it looks good, doesn't *quite* match), and the sort of "branching" effect between peaks. I hope that I might receive some additional advice/suggestions for achieving these effects, but for now I'll accept the only current answer because, while not perfect, it has helped tremendously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this. The main "wave cell" shape comes from subtracting the *Smooth f1* of a Voronoi texture from the "basic f1" of another identical Voronoi texture. To make the cells rough, I warped the input vectors with a Noise texture first. The ColorRamp makes the "bottom" flat, and the "cell wave crests" stick up, while the final mix with a Noise Texture makes the perfectly smooth part (thanks to the colorramp) slightly bumpy again. Ambient occlusion takes care of the colors (note, I set the distance *way* down in mine):

[image: Stucco]

Comment: It's definitely closer. A few questions: 1) For lack of better terminology, is there a way to make the peaks look more "vein-y," or to make them branch more, without altering the size width/length of the peaks (height alterations are fine)?, 2) How might you go about adding some more randomness or variation to the pattern? What I have on my end is great, but some of the littler details are lost (random bumps, varied stroke directions, etc.; I'll post what I have in an edit). 3. Is there a way that you know of to affect the shape of the spaces between peaks?

Comment: Play with the scale and detail of the noise texture going into the Vector Math. Also, try lowering the mix with white before the Vector Math (Add) node to increase the distortion amount of the cells. Change the slider positions on the ColorRamp to increase/decrease the height ands complexity of the crests.

Comment: I'm sure that I can find out through trial and error, but I thought I'd ask: is there any benefit to placing additional sliders onto the ColorRamp?

Comment: I'm not sure adding more steps to the colorramp will help much, but you should always try yourself. If you want more detail/variation in the pattern, consider making a second, smaller version (larger scale on the Voronoi nodes) and mix the 2 patterns together using yet another noise texture (scale<1) as the mix factor.